# Class does not name a type when used as return type inside another class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, builder

I'm facing this problem when trying to create a builder design-pattern, here is HtmlElement.h header file:

**Edit**
I included both headers and cpp implementations along with error generated and code causing the error in main.cpp

```
#ifndef BUILDER_HTMLELEMENT_H
#define BUILDER_HTMLELEMENT_H


#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "HtmlBuilder.h"

class HtmlElement {
    friend class HtmlBuilder;
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string text;
    std::vector<HtmlElement> elements;
    const int indent_size{2};
    HtmlElement()=default;
    HtmlElement(std::string, std::string);
public:
    std::string str(int indent=0)const;
    static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string &root_name);
};


#endif //BUILDER_HTMLELEMENT_H
```

And this is the builder class header file:

```
#ifndef BUILDER_HTMLBUILDER_H
#define BUILDER_HTMLBUILDER_H


#include "HtmlElement.h"


class HtmlBuilder {
private:
    HtmlElement root;
public:
    HtmlBuilder(const std::string &);
    HtmlBuilder &add_child(std::string, std::string);
    std::string str()const;
    operator HtmlElement()const{return root;}
};


#endif //BUILDER_HTMLBUILDER_H
```

The implementation for HtmlElement.cpp file:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "HtmlElement.h"

HtmlElement::HtmlElement(std::string name, std::string text) : name{std::move(name)},
                                                               text{std::move(text)} {}

std::string HtmlElement::str(int indent) const {
    std::ostringstream oss{};
    std::string i{std::string(indent_size * indent, ' ')};
    oss << i << "<" << name << ">" << std::endl;
    if (!text.empty())
        oss << std::string(indent_size * (indent + 1), ' ') << text << std::endl;
    for (const auto &element:elements)oss << element.str(indent + 1);
    oss << i << "</" << name << ">" << std::endl;

    return oss.str();
}
HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::build(const std::string &root_name) {return {root_name};}
```

And the implementation for HtmlBuilder.cpp file:

```
#include "HtmlBuilder.h"


HtmlBuilder::HtmlBuilder(const std::string &root_name) { root.name = root_name; }

HtmlBuilder &HtmlBuilder::add_child(std::string name, std::string text) {
    HtmlElement e{std::move(name), std::move(text)};
    root.elements.emplace_back(e);
    return *this;
}

std::string HtmlBuilder::str() const { return root.str(); }
```

Everything was compiling without any problem (and no issue with HtmlElement data member inside HtmlBuilder class) until I added this static function to the HtmlElement class:

```
static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string &root_name);
```

Although HtmlBuilder.h is included, I'm having the error of "HtmlBuilder does not name a type", I tried many solutions like declaring HtmlBuilder class ahead in HtmlElement and/or declaring HtmlElement class ahead in HtmlBuilder (both headers are included in each other's classes).

Could anyone please help why it's happening when I declared a return type on class function(build inside HtmlElement) of another(HtmlBuilder) and what would be the solution?

Please note, the only way I managed to make it work was by putting all classes together in the main.cpp!!

The code in main.cpp which generates the error:

```
HtmlElement builder2 = HtmlElement::build("ul").add_child("li", "hey")
            .add_child("li", "there");
    std::cout << builder2.str() << std::endl;
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**
This is the generated error code:

```
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/HtmlElement.cpp.o
In file included from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlBuilder.h:5,
                 from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlBuilder.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlElement.h:21:12: error: 'HtmlBuilder' does not name a type
   21 |     static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string &root_name);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/build.make:89: CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/HtmlBuilder.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlBuilder.h:5,
                 from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/main.cpp:4:
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlElement.h:21:12: error: 'HtmlBuilder' does not name a type
   21 |     static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string &root_name);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/main.cpp:58:41: error: 'build' is not a member of 'HtmlElement'
   58 |     HtmlElement builder2 = HtmlElement::build("ul").add_child("li", "hey")
      |                                         ^~~~~
In file included from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlElement.h:7,
                 from /cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlElement.cpp:2:
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlBuilder.h:11:5: error: 'HtmlElement' does not name a type
   11 |     HtmlElement root;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/HtmlBuilder.h:16:14: error: expected type-specifier before 'HtmlElement'
   16 |     operator HtmlElement()const{return root;}
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/HtmlElement.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/cmake-build-debug'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/cmake-build-debug'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/FluentBuilder.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/CppCourse/DesignPatterns/Builder/FluentBuilder/cmake-build-debug'
make: *** [Makefile:118: FluentBuilder] Error 2
```

Comment: (You should make this an answer instead of two lengthy comments)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, the implementations are included in a separate cpp file, I'll add the code for a clearer picture.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question, and also add a comment on the line where you get it. And please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude done! please review the edits, Thanks for your follow up dude :) and waiting for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to return a `HtmlBuilder` object, the code needs the full and complete definition of the class.

The problem is that you have a circular dependency between the `HtmlBuilder` and `HtmlElement` classes, so it's not possible to solve by simple `#include` of the other header file in its own header file.

*One* possible way to solve it is to define (implement) the `build` function separately, for example in a source file, where the full and complete definitions of both classes are available.

---

On another and unrelated note, only converting constructors (constructors taking a *single* argument) might need to be `explicit`.

Your two-argument `HtmlElement(std::string, std::string)` constructor can never be used in an implicit conversion and therefore doesn't have to be marked as explicit.

Comment: Thanks again for your follow up and help, I tried to do what you suggested, so I made only the declaration in header file:
```static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string &root_name);```
and the implementation in the cpp file:
```HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::build(const std::string &root_name) {return {root_name};}```
also removed the explicit, But still have same issue

Comment: @AstroMan Do you remember to `#include` the `HtmlBuilder` header file in the source file?

Comment: Yes of course :)
As I said dude, everything was compiling, linking and executing before including the static function with HtmlBuilder return!